# LaTeX Flow Stagger Arrows and Box Positions

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I have tried using edge and other methods and what I hope is to stagger the boxes and align the arrows as shown..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need anything special for that, just `positioning` and some node anchors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,minimum
        height=3.5em,minimum width=#1},box/.default=7em,>=stealth,very thick]
 \node[box=5.5em] (A){};
 \node[box,right=2cm of A] (B2){};
 \node[box,above=1cm of B2,xshift=0.5cm] (B1){};
 \node[box,below=1cm of B2,xshift=-0.5cm] (B3){};
 \draw[->] (A) -- (B2);
 \draw[<-] (B2.north east) -- (B2.north east|-B1.south);
 \draw[->] (B2.south west) -- (B2.south west|-B3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You *can* also use `chains`, but in this example this does not yet make sense IMHO.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,minimum
        height=3.5em,minimum width=#1},box/.default=7em,>=stealth,very thick]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=B going below,node distance=1cm,
    nodes={box,xshift=-5mm,on chain}]
  \node{};
  \node{};
  \node{};
 \end{scope}
 \node[box=5.5em,left=2cm of B-2] (A){};
 \draw[->] (A) -- (B-2);
 \draw[<-] (B-2.north east) -- (B-2.north east|-B-1.south);
 \draw[->] (B-2.south west) -- (B-2.south west|-B-3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```